# MySQL missing key_buffer_size in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have never really played around with mysql settings before, but on our new linux cloud server it appears that mysql is eating up all the memory till it crashes, then it cannot restart as there is no more memory to restart the service, I have to reboot the cloud server.

So I was looking at how I could tame the memory usage, and after reading about key_buffer_size (and another setting I cannot recall of the my head) I had a look at the my.cnf file, and there is nothing with this setting on it.  My my.cnf is as follows...

```
[client]
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql

[mysql]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

Without the key_buffer_size set... will it just keep eating up memory till it runs out?  Shouldn't this setting be set?

Cheers

Comment: Re-read what you wrote.  "It cannot restart, as there is no more memory to restart the service."  But wait: if the service has crashed, all of its memory is now freed, so that analysis shouldn't be right. The problem is not likely to be MySQL.  It's the victim of another memory hog: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem/25083#25083

Answer (score 0):

The default for key_buffer_size is 8M per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html

However, I would ask that you set these first (and restart MySQL) and see if the problem persists.

```
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

If after those settings are used, the problem persists, then it's likely not a configuration issue, but something deeper.

Additionally, see these:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31182/mysql-slowly-uses-memory-until-it-starts-to-use-swap

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/why-does-mysql-use-all-of-memory-and-goes-into-swap-when-doing-lots-of-delayed-i

Comment: Thanks... which section in the cnf should these go?

Comment: They go in the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: This answer is very outdated. The link to dev.mysql.com is dead. `key_buffer` is an unknown variable. May be you update it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kinds for the advice!

Turns out it was the innodb_buffer_pool_size.  It was set to high for my machine.  I have adjusted it as well as optimized how much memory Apache uses.  Everything seems to be running better and there is a bit of memory headroom.  Hope that fixes it.